# Debain Start Up Script - Google Cloud

Tags: linux, debian, scripting, startup-scripts

so I would like to know how to create a script the performs three basic commands.

```
sudo su - Admin
     cd ~/AMP
     ./ampinstmgr -a
```

This is what I got, I have also given it 777 perms.

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/run.sh
#

# Some things that run always
touch /var/lock/run

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
     sudo su - Admin
     cd ~/AMP
     ./ampinstmgr -a
    ;;
  stop)

    ;;
  *)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 3 commands

```
sudo su - Admin
 cd ~/AMP
 ./ampinstmgr -a
```

Simply use `sudo` to execute the command as user Admin directly (and don't rely on <kbd>~</kbd> expansion but use absolute paths in `sudo` commands):

```
sudo -u Admin /home/Admin/AMP/ampinstmgr -a
```

Comment: So is there anything that I have to do to make this script run in the init.d folder? I changed it to 

sudo -u Admin /home/Admin/AMP/ampinstmgr -a